# postcss can't find config when requiring a package's css file

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, webpack, postcss, webpacker

I'm trying to make `rails` work with `webpack` using `webpacker`. But when I deploy to production, it fails with:

```
   ERROR in /home/user/app/shared/~/css-loader!/home/user/app/shared/~/postcss-loader!/home/user/app/shared/~/sass-loader/lib/loader.js!/home/user/app/shared/~/bootstrap-fileinput/css/fileinput.css
   Module build failed: Error: No PostCSS Config found in: /home/user/app/shared/node_modules/bootstrap-fileinput/css
```

Since `.postcssrc.yml` is located at `/home/user/app/tmp/build-.../.postcssrc.yml`, which is not down the file tree relative to `/home/user/app/shared/node_modules/bootstrap-fileinput/css/fileinput.css`. Because I'm sharing `node_modules` dir between releases. What do I do, other then not share the dir?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to make it work by specifying config file [explicitly](https://github.com/postcss/postcss-loader/blob/1.3.3/index.js#L54-L62):

```
diff --git a/config/webpack/loaders/sass.js b/config/webpack/loaders/sass.js
index faba9d5..6fc902c 100644
--- a/config/webpack/loaders/sass.js
+++ b/config/webpack/loaders/sass.js
@@ -4,6 +4,11 @@ module.exports = {
   test: /\.(scss|sass|css)$/i,
   use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
     fallback: 'style-loader',
-    use: ['css-loader', 'postcss-loader', 'sass-loader']
+    use: ['css-loader', {
+      loader: 'postcss-loader',
+      options: {
+        config: '.postcssrc.yml',
+      },
+    }, 'sass-loader']
   })
 }
```

But that most likely disables config files that nodejs packages might have. Not sure if that matters.

Some more or less [relevant](https://github.com/postcss/postcss-loader/issues/92#issuecomment-276036682) [links](https://github.com/postcss/postcss-loader/issues/183#issuecomment-283634398).